# ¿Cómo agregar a Android Studio esos fondos de pantalla que se mueven con el movimiento del celular?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de fondos de pantalla en Android Studio, pero quiero añadir uno de esos fondos de pantalla 3d que se mueven con el movimiento del celular.

Encontré una página llamada DEPTHY, que me permite crear el efecto 3d que quiero, lo que hago es descargar los fondos ya echos en formato png y luego convertirlos a formato stl y de ahí a formato .fbx para que android studio pueda aceptarlos, pero creo que lo estoy haciendo mal. El punto es que cuando lo agrego a la ruta **res/drawable** y lo agrego a mi código, Android Studio no acepta la extensión .fbx o .obj.

Este es el mensaje que recibo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si lo estoy agregando a la carpeta incorrecta o si el formato de archivo es incorrecto. Lo probé con la extensión .gif pero no da el efecto deseado.

Gracias por su ayuda.